# PFPurchase Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException: "You cannot purchase a product that is in the process of being purchased"

Tags: ios, parse-platform

When a user taps purchase iap confirmation button twice, Parse CRASHES with:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException

"You cannot purchase a product that is in the process of being purchased"

PFPurchase.m line 108
```

Is it really up to the app to prevent this?

[Parse 1.4.1]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, it's really your responsibility to prevent this.

Try a helper class with a `BOOL pfPurchaseInProgress` set initially to NO, then change it as your are running your purchase. Something like this:

```
typedef void (^ CompletionBlock)();

(void)buyProduct:(NSString *)productID withCompletionBlock:(CompletionBlock)block 
{ 
    if (!self.pfPurchaseInProgress) {
      self.pfPurchaseInProgress = YES;
      [PFPurchase buyProduct:productID block:^(NSError *error) {
          self.pfPurchaseInProgress = NO;
          if (!error) {
              block();
          }
      }];
    } 
}
```